# Idempotent Bash Script for a Patch and requirements file

Tags: pip, patch, pypdf, idempotent, requirements.txt

I have a python project with its own requirements file. The project also has its own virtualenv, with one of the packages being 'pyPdf'. The library has a bug and I wrote a patch to fix the bug.

```
--- venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py 2014-07-17 17:04:57.000000000 +0530
+++ pypdf_fixer.py  2014-07-19 01:19:53.176877332 +0530
@@ -1726,7 +1726,10 @@
     m.update(p_entry)
     # 5. Pass the first element of the file's file identifier array to the MD5
     # hash function.
-    m.update(id1_entry)
+    if isinstance(id1_entry, str):
+        m.update(id1_entry)
+    else:
+        m.update(id1_entry.original_bytes)
     # 6. (Revision 3 or greater) If document metadata is not being encrypted,
     # pass 4 bytes with the value 0xFFFFFFFF to the MD5 hash function.
     if rev >= 3 and not metadata_encrypt:
```

Lets call this file as pypdf.patch. I run the patch using the Linux patch command.

```
$ patch venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py < pypdf.patch
```

I need to write a bash script to do 2 things with Idempotent property(meaning running the script multiple times should be the same as running it a single time)

1) Run through the requirements file with various library requirements(example Flask==0.10.1 etc, including a git+ssh requirement) and do a pip install for all the libraries.

2) Apply the patch to the pypdf library.

Appreciate any leads on this front. Kindly take note of 'Idempotency'.

PS: My requirements.txt file looks like this.(I do a pip install - r requirements.txt under the virtualenv to install the libraries)

```
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
...
pyPdf==1.13
git+ssh://git@something.co.uk/some-production-library.git
```

Thanks

Comment: Going through the requirements file is trivial..I believe its just emulating "pip install -r requirements" ie doing a "pip install" line by line. pip already is idempotent here as the version number is mentioned. 
I am not sure how to do the same for the patch. One way that I have tried is copying the corrected file to project directory permanently. And for patching, do a "diff" with the library file, and apply the patch only if there is a diff. I set this up few min back but not sure if this is the right way to do it. If there is any better solution, will be grateful for the response.

Comment: I am not coding up for you but I will give you a tip with patch. look at `-R` and `--dry-run` if Reverse was possible it means that the patch have already been applied. Dry-run is simulation only the file won't be changed.

Comment: Awesome thank you..this should solve the problem. Much cleaner solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking out for similar script. Save the script in projectfolder/bin/

```
#!/bin/bash -e

BASEDIR=`dirname $0`/..

if [ ! -d "$BASEDIR/venv" ]; then
    virtualenv $BASEDIR/venv
    echo "Virtualenv created with name venv."
fi

source $BASEDIR/venv/bin/activate

if [ ! -f "$BASEDIR/venv/updated" -o $BASEDIR/requirements.txt -nt $BASEDIR/venv/updated ]; then
    pip install -r $BASEDIR/requirements.txt
    touch $BASEDIR/venv/updated
    echo "Requirements installed."
fi

patch $BASEDIR/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py -p0 -N --dry-run --silent < $BASEDIR/pypdf.patch
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "applying patch"
    #apply the patch
    patch $BASEDIR/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py -p0 -N < $BASEDIR/pypdf.patch
fi
```